# Good-looking sphere in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

I've been trying to plot a (3d) sphere with some curves on it using Matplotlib, but so far the my results are disappointing.

[image: What I've got.]

I've tried with several RGB colors, opacities and colormaps, but the output is similar.

How could I do something like this Bloch Sphere? That's just what I'm looking for.

[image: What I'd like.]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! I think it would be a good idea to add some code to your question - this would help us reproduce the sphere you are currently getting and also show people that you've made a good faith effort to solve the problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To get a 3d plot more similar to the one you're showing, you can add some circular curves and lines along each axis. For example:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Make data
r = 10
u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
v = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)
x = r * np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))
y = r * np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
z = r * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v))

# Plot the surface
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, color='linen', alpha=0.5)

# plot circular curves over the surface
theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
z = np.zeros(100)
x = r * np.sin(theta)
y = r * np.cos(theta)

ax.plot(x, y, z, color='black', alpha=0.75)
ax.plot(z, x, y, color='black', alpha=0.75)

## add axis lines
zeros = np.zeros(1000)
line = np.linspace(-10,10,1000)

ax.plot(line, zeros, zeros, color='black', alpha=0.75)
ax.plot(zeros, line, zeros, color='black', alpha=0.75)
ax.plot(zeros, zeros, line, color='black', alpha=0.75)

plt.show()
```

[image]